# How to ignore OSError: [Errno 2] in Python, os linux, usbtmc

Tags: python, linux, compiler-errors, usb

I'm using python to communicate with Oscilloscope and Waveform generator via usbmtc and sometimes my usb ports are changing.

So I wrote a function to detect current device:

But if I don't have device **usbtmc1** connected, then I have the following error:

Is there are any options to ignore the error?

Comment: @SiddheshMhatre, the pass is correct, and the first part of code is working.
so what I have is:
waveform and then error

Answer (score 2):

Use the built-in `try` to ignore errors in Python.

Combining with `logging`, you can log the error on screen or to a file.

```
import logging

for x in range(0, 3):
    dev= '/dev/usbtmc' + str(x)
    try:
        currentUsb = usb.tmc(dev)
        currentUsb.write("*IDN?")
        name = currentUsb.read(300)
        if name.find('DSO') >-1:
            scope= usb.tmc(dev)
            print 'scope '

        elif name.find('33621A') >-1:
            waveform = usb.tmc(dev)
            print 'waveform'
    except OSError:
        logging.info('Something is wrong')
        pass
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, just tried your code, but it didn't work. But you gave me very good pointer what I can do!

Comment: My code is crushing before if loop, in the following line:     currentUsb = usb.tmc(dev)

Comment: @IvanShorokhov Try the code again. I have fixed it.

Comment: @IvanShorokhov `logging.info('Something is wrong')` is optional, you can comment it out by adding `#` in front of it as so `#logging.info('Something is wrong')`

Comment: @IvanShorokhov no problem Glad I can help!